# de Sitter reviews?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, resource-recommendations, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime

I'm very interested in learning more about de Sitter and anti-de Sitter spaces and their applications in GR and cosmology.  Can anyone recommend favorite review articles -- or, more likely, a series of review articles -- that could bring me up to speed on recent applications and developments?

Comment: My apologies.  I'm looking for something which presumes basic knowledge of GR at, say, the level of Hartle's Gravity: An Introduction to Einstein's General Relativity.  And preferably something with his level of physical intuition/insight and mathematical rigor.

Comment: Hawking and Ellis includes a pretty insightful description of anti de Sitter space (and I think of de Sitter as well), although this of course won't tell about anything recent and describes only the exact solutions.

Comment: For dS: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0110007
For AdS: https://web.archive.org/web/20180319192552/http://www.fysik.su.se/~ingemar/Kurs.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a book (I'm sorry not an article), that I was reading, which includes a chapter called "de-Sitter Spacetime" and a chapter called " anti-de Sitter Spacetime". It is "Einstein  gravity in a nutshell" by Antony Zee.